# Удаление файлов после завершения сеанса

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуйте. Уже два дня сижу и ломаю голову над одной интересной задачей. Делаю что-то вроде редактора PHP кода. После нажатия на кнопку "Показать" у меня показывается результат этого кода.

Теперь про внутреннюю часть: когда я нажимаю на кнопку "Показать" у меня создаётся папка с названием текущей сессии в которой хранится файл с данным php кодом. Но не задача, со временем папка с примерами кодов будет весить тонну. Как мне можно осуществить, что бы когда сеанс завершался, папка удалялась? Думал через проверку активности сессии, но не нашёл примера, как проверять её активность. Может кто знает, как можно реализовать данную плюшку. Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, если код в папке изменяется, то дата изменения файлов тоже, то есть сессия активная. Можно удалять папку, если файлы с кодом в ней долгое время не изменялись.

Comment: Ну тут сложно просчитать время. Вдруг пользователь отошёл на 2 часа, пришёл, а сессия не активировалась. Хотя ваш вариант интересен. Если не будет лучше, отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте наоборот. Включите создание папки, внутри которой создаёте подпапки для сессий (хотя я в принципе не понимаю, что было обозвано термином "название текущей сессии", а если это и вправду некий идентификатор сессии - то как он может повториться при следующем запуске). И при старте приложения удаляйте из этой папки (или подпапки, имя которой соответствует этому странному термину "название текущей сессии") весь валяющийся там хлам, тихо игнорируя ошибки.

Почему ошибки и почему игнорировать? Пользователь может захотеть сохранять что-то между сессиями. Редактор этот, в конце концов, может тупо упасть - не терять же то, что было сделано, только потому, что оно повесило редактор? Ну так вот - всем таким файлам просто присвойте RO, они и не удалятся.

Comment: При нажатии на "Показать", создаётся папка с ID текущей сессии. Если пользователь зайдёт в следующий раз, я не могу удалить ту прошлую сессию не запомнив её где-то (запоминать я её не хочу). Если мне удалять все папки, которые там есть, то выйдет плохая практика, т.к. текоторые папки могут быть в данный момент активны (т.е. папки, которые используются сейчас другими пользователями)

Comment: _При нажатии на "Показать", создаётся папка с ID текущей сессии._ По смыслу она должна создаваться при старте приложения. И открываться эксклюзивно или хотя бы с блокированием любых действий, кроме скана и чтения, на всё время работы приложения,- это, кстати, убережёт её от удаления другой копией приложения или сторонним софтом. И удаляться в процессе выгрузки приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вызвать функцию `session_set_save_handler()` и установить обработчик `destroy`/`gc`. Когда PHP будет убивать сессию, он вызовет Ваш обработчик и в нем Вы почистите каталог

Comment: Можно подробнее? В сессиях почти ноль